# JQuery removing buttons dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am adding buttons based on an array.  The problem I am having is that every time I add another name to the array, it prints out all the buttons not just the one I added.  I am wondering how would I erase all the old buttons before I add the array of buttons.

Here is my code

```
        socket.on('usernames', function(data){
        console.log(data);
        for(i=0; i <data.length; i++){
            // html += data[i] + "<br/>";
            $input = $('<input type="button"/></br>');
            $input.val(data[i]);
            $input.appendTo($("#contentWrap"));
        }
        // $users.html(html);
    });
```

Below is an image.  Test is the name of the first button and every time I add a new button it prints the entire array again.  Is there a way to delete the old buttons?
[image]

Comment: I suggest reading through http://learn.jquery.com. It'll only take a couple hours and will be hugely beneficial to you.

Comment: Since we don't know what else is in `contentWrap`... `$("#contentWrap > input[type=button],#contentWrap > input[type=button]+br").remove();`

Comment: @squint I reopened this question as the dupe you selected wasn't really a dupe as the OP specifically asks how to do it in jQuery. I'm not saying there isn't a dupe - so please feel free to post a link if you can find a more relevant question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: True. If I look for another, I'll drop you a note.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `empty()` method before you loop:

```
socket.on('usernames', function(data){
    var $contentWrap = $("#contentWrap").empty();

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $input = $('<input type="button"/></br>');
        $input.val(data[i]);
        $input.appendTo($contentWrap);
    }
});
```

Also note that you can improve performance and tidy the code by creating a single HTML string and setting the `html()` property to only require one DOM call. Try this:

```
socket.on('usernames', function(data){
    var html = data.map(function(value) {
        return '<input type="button" value="' + value + '"/></br>'
    }).join('');
    $('#contentWrap').html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [.empty()](https://api.jquery.com/empty/) on the parent element before appending the elements again.

```
$("#contentWrap").empty();

for(i=0; i <data.length; i++){
    // html += data[i] + "<br/>";
    $input = $('<input type="button"/></br>');
    $input.val(data[i]);
    $input.appendTo($("#contentWrap"));
}
```